# GameObject With Background Covers GameObject Without Background

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject, layers

so I have two sprites, a box and an X animation (I'm making Tic-Tac-Toe). So, in the code, when I click on the box, it instantiates the X animation at the right place. The X animation does not have a background, but the box does. However, when it instantiates, it puts it *behind* the box.

This doesn't make sense to me, but even when I move it around in the editor, moving it across the box puts it behind it. Which is interesting, since neither have layers. And even when I do put layers on (a higher layer on the X animation), it still goes behind. Take a look:

[image: Disappearing GameObject]

Any ideas on why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

**EDIT:** Here's my hierarchy and inspector:

[image: Hierarchy and Inspector]

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your components and heirarchy?

Comment: Higher Sorting Layer or Order in Layer? Do they have the same depth (Z coordinate)?

Comment: @wondra Yep, they both have the same layer (though even if the X animation is higher, it's still behind), and the Z coordinate for both is 0 (and when changed for the X animation, it stays behind).

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not sure why, I tried messing around, and putting the Z-radius of the X Animation *behind* the box, it actually showed up in front of it (with the Z-radius of the X animation being -2 and the box being 0).

Comment: Since the default camera looks along the positive z axis, smaller / more negative numbers are actually closer to the camera. So -2 is in front of 0..You can verify this by putting your scene view into 3D mode and looking at your content from the side.

Answer (score 0):

From your edit, it looks like you’ve selected the X animation GameObject. I see that it’s on the Default sorting layer. See SpriteRenderer component’s layer. If you have multiple layers, put the X animation on the a foreground layer. You can create new layers if you don’t have any.

If you are not able to create/use a different layer due to some reason, you can change the Order in Layer property of the SpriteRenderer component. It is currently set to 0. You can try changing it to 1 or more.

Putting the X animation slightly closer towards the camera, meaning a slight negative offset than the box, will also work. But remember, if you move the X animation in z axis, and you’re using a perspective camera, the result might not be what you are looking for. I would prefer doing it in either of the 2 above mentioned ways